# Finding a pair from a 2D vector i

Tags: vector

Finding a pair from a 2D vector if it's second element is not present in the first element of another pair

Finding a pair from a 2D vector if it's second element is not present in the first element of another pair

Answer (score 0):

Please add more clarity to problem.

As I got:
create a map for first elements indicating if first element is present or not by iterating once.
In second iteration look for second element and search if it is there in map as or not.

If not present then return it, else move to next one.